# Pandas customized group aggregation

Tags: pandas, grouping, customization, aggregation

I have a question regarding pandas and customised group aggregations to find the most efficient way to calculate my values. Here is my code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

listA = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') * 2
listB = listA[::-1]
listC = listA[::2] * 2
listD = "Won"
data1 = range(52) 
data2 = range(52,104) 
data3 = range(104,156)

rawStructure = [('A', listA),
                ('B', listB),
                ('C', listC),
                ('D', listD),
                ('Data1', data1),
                ('Data2', data2),
                ('Data3', data3)]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(rawStructure, orient='columns')

df.loc[40:,"D"] = "Lost" 

def customfct(x,y,z):
    print('x',x)
    data = round(((x.sum() + y.sum())/z.sum()) * 100,2)
    return  data

def f(row): 
    val1 = row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data1'].sum()
    val2 = row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data2'].sum()
    val3 = row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data3'].sum()
    val4 = customfct(row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data1'], row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data2'], row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data3'])
    return val1, val2, val3, val4

groupByCriteria = "C"
agg = df[:].groupby(by=groupByCriteria).apply(f)
print(agg)
```

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to make groupings and apply customised calculations (like function "customfct", which uses different columns (Data1, Data2,Data3)). My first approach was something like you could see here: http://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/ but it seems to be infeasible to create a formula which isn't constraint on one column (e.g lambda x: max(x) - min(x)). Furthermore, how would you return a pandas data frame instead of a pandas series (with a tuple)? Thanks in advance!

That is my current output (which is correct, but I guess there is a more efficient way):

[Pandas output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DSn5.png)

Comment: What is your specific first question? Maybe actual data, current results, desired results will help.

Comment: I did some changes in my original post, do you need anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider aggregating all *Data* columns in one `groupby()` call and then create a new column for *val4*. Then merge aggregation back to original dataframe.

```
# EQUIVALENT EXAMPLE DATA
listA = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') * 2
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': listA, 'B': listA[::-1], 'C': listA[::2] * 2,
                   'D': ["Won" for i in range(40)] + ["Lost" for i in range(40,52)],
                   'Data1': range(52), 'Data2': range(52,104), 'Data3': range(104,156)})

# ADJUSTED METHOD
groupByCriteria = "C"
grp = df[df['D']=="Won"].groupby(by=groupByCriteria).sum().reset_index()\
                              .rename(columns={'Data1':'val1','Data2':'val2','Data3':'val3'})
grp['val4'] = round(((grp['val1'] + grp['val2'])/grp['val3']) * 100,2)

agg = df.merge(grp, on='C').sort_values('Data1').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

In timing comparisons, adjusted code is markedly faster. Do note: your method was adjusted to return a dataframe and not a series.

```
def origfct():
    def customfct(x,y,z):
        #print('x',x)
        data = round(((x.sum() + y.sum())/z.sum()) * 100,2)
        return data

    def f(row): 
        row['val1'] = row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data1'].sum()
        row['val2'] = row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data2'].sum()
        row['val3'] = row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data3'].sum()
        row['val4'] = customfct(row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data1'],
                                row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data2'],
                                row.loc[(row['D'] == "Won"), 'Data3'])
        return row

    groupByCriteria = "C"
    agg = df[:].groupby(by=groupByCriteria).apply(f)
    return agg

def newsetup():
    groupByCriteria = "C"
    grp = df[df['D']=="Won"].groupby(by=groupByCriteria).sum().reset_index()\
                           .rename(columns={'Data1':'val1','Data2':'val2','Data3':'val3'})
    grp['val4'] = round(((grp['val1'] + grp['val2'])/grp['val3']) * 100,2)

    agg = df.merge(grp, on='C').sort_values('Data1').reset_index(drop=True)
    return agg


python -mtimeit -n'100' -s'import pyscript as test' 'test.origfct()'
# 100 loops, best of 3: 198 msec per loop

python -mtimeit -n'100' -s'import pyscript as test' 'test.newsetup()'
# 100 loops, best of 3: 16 msec per loop
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Very nice approach to make those calculations in a fast way. I haven't thought of rejoining tables. Thanks a lot!