# Custom Grouper object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How can I implement a custom `pandas.Grouper` class?

In other words - which methods/interfaces should the subclass of `pandas.Grouper` implement so that it can operate as an argument of `DataFrame.groupby`?

As a brief **toy example**: writing a grouper class that will group dataframe based on the first 5 symbols of some particular column of strings. Indeed this is easily achieved using existing methods:

```py
df.groupby(df[column].str[:5])
```

But what I'm looking for is implementing some `NameGrouper` class, so that the operation is done by:

```py
df.groupby(NameGrouper(column))
```

p.s.
There're quite some questions on SO about tailoring group-by to a particular needs (e.g. [Pandas: Custom group-by function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970530/pandas-custom-group-by-function), [Pandas customized group aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982290/pandas-customized-group-aggregation), [Pandas groupby custom groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59864763/pandas-groupby-custom-groups)) with answers using standard pandas functionality. But what I'm interested in an extension of the default pandas functionality.

Comment: show example input, and expected output

Comment: Hello @sygneto, the particular input/output does not matter, since it is just a toy example, and the question is about the implementation of an interface.

Answer (score 1):

> **Important Note**: In practice, you never need to subclass `pandas.Grouper`, and I would generally advise against doing so. It's API is internal and may change between versions without notice or warning.

**Note**: If you need to use custom logic in your `groupby` function, and no other option works for you, you can always fall back to:

```py
def custom_fn(df):
    return series  # a column of group indices

(
    df
    .assign(custom_groups=custom_fn)
    .groupby("custom_groups")
    ...
)
```

If at this point, you are still reading, then I assume that you are aware and have accepted that this is for educational purposes only :). In this case, you can create your own `pandas.Grouper` subclass by overwriting exactly one method: `_get_grouper`. It takes as input an `NDFrame` (aka `df`) and a boolean (`validate`) and - in pandas v1.5.3 - returns a `(None, Grouper, NDFrame)` triplet. (The `None` is for compatibility.)

For example, we can create a `VowelGrouper`, which groups the dataframe based on the number of vowels inside a given string column:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import get_grouper

class VowelCounter(pd.Grouper):
    """Group by number of vowels.
    """

    def _get_grouper(self, df:pd.DataFrame, validate: bool = True):
        groups = df[self.key].map(lambda x: sum(map(x.count, "aeiou")))
        groups.name = "vowel_count"
        grouper, _, _ = get_grouper(
            df, 
            groups,
            axis=self.axis,
            level=self.level,
            sort=self.sort,
            validate=validate,
            dropna=self.dropna,
        )

        return None, grouper, df
```

In the above, `groups` is a hashmap that maps the dataframe's index onto its group label. It can be pretty much anything that can be understood as a `index_key->hash` mapping, e.g., a dict, `pd.Series` (used above), callable, column name (str), etc. For a detailed list of which types of hashmaps are supported, I recommend having a look at `pandas.core.groupby.grouper.get_grouper`'s source code (which is fairly easy to understand).

`get_grouper` is another internal function, which takes the hashmap we created and turns it into a `pandas.core.groupby.ops.BaseGrouper`. The `BaseGrouper` is the object that eventually creates the `pandas.core.groupby.grouper.Grouping` objects that make up the `groupby` selections. You can explore these at your leisure.

To use our newly created `VowelGrouper`, we simply pass it to `Groupby` as we would normally do. Given a dataframe

```py
import string

silly_df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict({
    "integer":np.arange(10, 0, -1),
    "char":list("abcdefghij"),
    "fruit":["apple", "bunana"] * 5,
    "random_string": np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 100).view(dtype="<U10")
})
```

|  | integer | char | fruit | random_string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | a | apple | cujhtsutjj |
| 1 | 9 | b | bunana | vqxlxuyrao |
| 2 | 8 | c | apple | reocupqhvw |
| 3 | 7 | d | bunana | umahpirheg |
| 4 | 6 | e | apple | yxjdfyqjmp |
| 5 | 5 | f | bunana | tiolonmvjw |
| 6 | 4 | g | apple | jebzzhspsd |
| 7 | 3 | h | bunana | giorkxlyzq |
| 8 | 2 | i | apple | mvzkovpnmt |
| 9 | 1 | j | bunana | cokbxvqijo |

we can group it by the `fruit` and the number of vowels in `random_string` and apply our usual aggregations on it

```py
(
    silly_df
    .groupby(["fruit", VowelCounter("random_string")])
    .agg({"integer": "mean", "char": "sum"})
    .reset_index()
)
```

|  | fruit | vowel_count | integer | char |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | apple | 0 | 8 | ae |
| 1 | apple | 1 | 2 | i |
| 2 | apple | 3 | 6 | cg |
| 3 | bunana | 1 | 6.33333 | bdh |
| 4 | bunana | 2 | 1 | j |
| 5 | bunana | 5 | 5 | f |